# How to set a span value with capybara?

Tags: ruby, capybara

Does anyone know how to set a value to span tag using capybara?

I tried using `element.set` or `element.send_keys`, they only selected the targeted element without modifing the previous value.

```
<div data-offset-key="bbpvo-0-0" class="_1mf _1mj"><span data-offset-key="bbpvo-0-0"><span data-text="true">aa</span></span></div>
```

HTML snippet is above, I want to set **aa** to **bb**.

Answer (score 2):

Capybara is designed to emulate a user - A user can't edit a span unless there's some sort of javascript widget attached to it.  If you have a JS widget attached to the span you would need to perform whatever actions a user would do in order to edit the span.  So you say the user has to click on the span and then type on the span - if that is so then you could try something like

```
span = find('span[data-text="true"]')
span.click
span.send_keys("new content", :enter)  # if enter is needed to end the editing
```

which may work - although I'm going to guess the element actually gets replaced with an input or something after it's clicked on, in which case you need to figure out what those elements are (using the browsers inspector) and then find and use send_keys or set on that element instead

Comment: umm -- there is no limit on an item having to have an id for you to interact with it --  what actions exactly does a user have to perform to edit the content you're trying to edit - ie - the user has to click on the span with data-text=true and then type? or do they have to click on something else first? Once you know that then you can just have capybara replicate those actions - also when they click on the span (if thats what the user has to do) does it get replaced with other elements?

Comment: thanks@Tom Walpole, but that's totally the facebook's page, and yes, we can use js/jquery to perform  the edit action, but unfortunately, it seems we only can use js when there is an id attached that span, but here we don't have it. when I tried that, it throwed error: 2.1.6 :005 > page.execute_script("$(\"#{find(:css,'span[data-text="true"]')}\").html('New Text');")
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::JavascriptError: <![EX[["Tried to get element with id of \"%s\" but it is not present on the page.","#<Capybara::Node::Element:0xad40bac>"]]]>
can you show me how to use js to change the span text?

Comment: The $ you're trying to call is from jQuery but facebooks page doesn't load jQuery -- to do it via JS you need to use just basic DOM methods  `document.querySelector('span[data-text="true"]').innerHTML = "New Text";` or something like that - obviously you'll need to scope the selector used to get the element you need - or, as I said previously. define what actions a user would have to do and then replicate those actions using capybaras api

Comment: what the user do is clicking that span then typing something else. the user firstly need to click Edit post button, i have replicate that move using capybara. but here I don't know how to replicate typing characters action when the element has a span tag. the normally way doesn't work(find(:css,'span[data-text="true"]').set "update_info"), after I typing this, page only selected those previous characters but without changing them, don't know why, so I assume does it relate to the span? if it is an input or textarea, I didn't run into this issue.

Comment: ah, facebooks page doesn't load jQuery, good to know that, thanks. when I typed document.querySelector('span[data-text="true"]').innerHTML = "New Text"; within irb mode, it doesn't return any error message, but the message on facebook's page didn't really be changed. any clue?

Comment: that will match the first span[data-text="true"] on the page -- are you sure there are none before where you're looking?  As I said it would need scoping correctly to get the exact element you want - you can call querySelectorAll('span[data-text="true"]') instead of querySelector to see how many matches there are - also I updated the answer above with info on the capybara rather than JS solution

Comment: thanks, the way you suggested using capyabara is exaclty what i do originally, unfortunately, it doesn't work. after typing this(span.native.send_keys("new content", :enter)
 => "" 
) it didn't report any error, but the message didn't be changed on facebook's page. and also using querySelectorAll, it only returns 1. sigh...

Comment: I still suscept this is becasue of span, if it is input or textarea, using the capyare's send_keys or set methods, they both work, but when it is span, seems no way to make it work. I just did a test, if I load jQuery first, then using .html method work perfectly. here if I want to use pure js.  is this the right way to use within irb? page.execte_script('document.querySelector('span[data-text="true"]').innerHTML = "New Text";')

Comment: you need to escape the 's in that (and spell execute correctly)- but otherwise - yes

Comment: Thanks very much, @Tom Walpole, this finally works. to short summary, when the element is a span, we seems cannot use normal capybara way, but we can use pure js way like page.execute_script('document.querySelector('selector').innerHTML="new Text";')

Answer (score 0):

To set text in span value,jquery can be used with capybara as shown below:

```
page.execute_script("$("<span css selector>").text("testing")");
```

or

```
page.execute_script("$("<span css selector>").html("testing <b>1 2 3</b>")");
```